# powershell output html behaviour

Tags: html, powershell, scripting

So i have this weird issue with this Powershell script that i use.

The script  has a function that gathers information about several domain computers and stores them into variables. Then it passes those vars as arguments to another function. This other function creates html tags conditionally (green cell if ping succeeds, red cell if ping fails, and so on with other columns as well. I use three files (containing ips of three areas where computers are located) to feed the function that gathers information and three tables are built.

Everything works fine EXCEPT for one weird (to me at least) thing... Every single time i run the script, the 10th ip produces four rows of html data, of which the first is ping successful, the rest are red cells... For the next two tables, the 12th ip does the same thing except it only creates one duplicate of table row. I tried switching the order of the ips in the file, as i thought it had something to do with the machines being pinged, but the same thing happens no matter what ip is at those positions in the file.

I can’t seem to figure this out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Need to see some code...

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. So.. i can't find any way to attach and i don't know what to leave out - the script has much more than 500 chars. I'll try to post it in multiple parts...  `function status_p17 {$pingstatus = test-connection -comp $computername -count 1 -quiet
   $pcname = gwmi win32_computersystem -computername $computername -ea Stop
   $services = gwmi win32_service -computername $computername | where { $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running' } ... `

Comment: `$DriveC = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $computername | where -Property Name -eq 'C:' | Select-Object Size,Freespace, @{ Name = "Size (GB)" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f( $_.Size / 1gb) } }, @{ Name = "Free Space (GB)" ; Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) } }, @{ Name = "Percent Free" ; Expression = { "{0:P0}" -f( $_.FreeSpace / $_.Size ) } }` (and similar for drive D).

Comment: $processes = import-csv .\p17prox\$computername.csv
   $diffprox = diff -ReferenceObject $processes -DifferenceObject ( gwmi win32_process -ComputerName $computername | where -Property Name -NotLike '*host*' | select Name ) -Property Name

Comment: I pass my the vars to another function with `statusrows $pcname $services $DriveC $DriveD $pingstatus $computername $diffprox`

Comment: You should ignore any missing braces, they're probably typos or omitted code - i tried to keep it as neat as possible for these posts. Now the statusrows function: `function statusrows
  {
  param ($pcname,$services,$DriveC,$DriveD,$pingstatus,$computername,$diffprox)
$proxcount = 0
$servcount = 0
while($proxcount -ne $diffprox.name.count)
{
$proxtable += "<tr><td>" + $diffprox.name[$proxcount] + "</td></tr>"
$proxcount++
}
while($servcount -ne $services.name.count)
{
$servtable += "<tr><td>" + $services.name[$servcount] + "</td></tr>"
$servcount++
}
$tableEntry = "<tr>"
`

Comment: `if ($pingstatus)
{
$tableEntry += "<td bgcolor='#387C44' align=center>" + $pcname.name + "</td>"
}
else
{
$tableEntry += "<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center>" + $pcname.name + "</td>"
}

if ($services -eq $null) 
{
$tableEntry += "<td bgcolor='#387C44' align=center>All services are OK</td>"
}
else
{
$tableEntry += "<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center><table id='intratable' width='100%'>" + $servtable + "</table></td>"
}
` And then it goes on with `if ($diffprox -eq $null)` etc, and `if ($DriveC.freespace -gt $DriveC.size/15)` etc.

Comment: and at the end of the func `$tableEntry += "</tr>"
add-content .\miau.html $tableEntry}`. Finally, `$lineheader = "<table id='systable' align='left'><tr><td colspan=5 class='headertd'> Table 1 </td></tr>"
add-content .\miau.html $lineheader
add-content .\miau.html $columns
gc .\iplist1.txt | status_p17
add-content .\miau.html $endtable
` goes 3 times for each list of ips, and `add-content .\miau.html $htmlend` Sorry for such clanky posts, i couldn't figure out a way to post this.

Comment: @andyb - I have multiple issues with this script. For once, there's the problem that i mentioned - multiple output - same symptom even with different computers. Another issue - with the process comparison part: for some computers it displays the full name of the process that is missing or is in plus. For others though, it only displays the first one letter of it (ie m for mstsc, or w for wuauclt). I can't seem to realize why is that.

Comment: Have you tried testing the functions in isolation?